# Ext Gwt setVisible results in disappearing fields

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, gxt

I'm having an issue where I have 4 form fields in a fieldset. If certain conditions are met, I use `setVisible(true/false)` to hide or show the fieldset.

I'm running into a problem where I originally hide a fieldset, but when I make it appear, it doesn't display the labels and textfield boxes.

If I do it in reverse, where I show the fieldset, then hide it later, I have no problem switching between the views and having it show up properly.

I use an HBoxLayout for the fieldset. I'm wondering if it's the layout that could potentially be causing the problem or maybe it's the rendering order?

Does anyone have a workaround or solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found was removing and adding the fields again. It's still not identical, the fields seem to be pushed over a bit from the left side, but it at least shows up again.